# Passenger throwing error for Sinatra app on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, passenger

I am trying to start Passenger with a Sinatra app on an Amazon EC2 instance and I get the following error:

```
    $ passenger start -e production
    =============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
    PID file: /home/ec2-user/github/mainpage/tmp/pids/passenger.3000.pid
    Log file: /home/ec2-user/github/mainpage/log/passenger.3000.log
    Environment: production
    Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:3000/

    You can stop Phusion Passenger Standalone by pressing Ctrl-C.
    Problems? Check https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html#troubleshooting
    ===============================================================================
    App 29028 stdout: 
    App 29028 stdout: 
    [ 2015-01-20 05:16:52.8259 28997/7fb5c6463700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/ec2-user/github/mainpage: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
      Error ID: 0ad6d346
      Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-911MCI.html
      Message from application: cannot load such file -- json (LoadError)
      /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mime-types-2.4.3/lib/mime/type.rb:4:in `require'
      /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mime-types-2.4.3/lib/mime/type.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
      /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mime-types-2.4.3/lib/mime/types.rb:3:in `require'
      /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mime-types-2.4.3/lib/mime/types.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
      /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail.rb:9:in `require'
      /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail.rb:9:in `<module:Mail>'
      /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
      /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/pony-1.11/lib/pony.rb:1:in `require'
      /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/pony-1.11/lib/pony.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
      /home/ec2-user/github/mainpage/app.rb:9:in `require'
      /home/ec2-user/github/mainpage/app.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
      config.ru:1:in `require'
      config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
      /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
      /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
      config.ru:1:in `new'
      config.ru:1:in `<main>'
      /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.57/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
      /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.57/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
      /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.57/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
      /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.57/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
      /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.57/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'


    [ 2015-01-20 05:16:52.8332 28997/7fb5bffff700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 0ad6d346. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

Here is my config.ru file:

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

and my gem file:

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'pony'
gem 'passenger'
```

Is the error related to json? I tried installing the json gem but I still get this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally get it working....
I had to manually add `gem 'json'` into my Gemfile and then did `bundle install`. After reading the errors, I figured that it had something to do with the pony gem. I am guessing that there was a dependency for pony (json gem) that was not being picked up by the bundler.